# Formatting filesystem in partitioned loop file corrupts partition table

Tags: linux, partitioning, filesystems

I created an approximately 3 gig file named test and partitioned it with `fdisk`. I then setup a loop device with that file (and an offset) in order to format an ext4 filesystem in the second partition. However, after I do this, my partition table seems to have been truncated! I'm pretty sure I have calculated the offset properly...

Why is this happening?

Notice that this partition table has a lot of partitions. I had to increase my kernel's `max_loop` setting to get more than the normal 8 loop devices. Currently, `max_loop` is set to 32.

Here is captured output showing exactly what's going on:

```
steve@steve-VirtualBox:/s/src/scripted/image$ ls -l test
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3072000000 Jul 21 17:13 test
steve@steve-VirtualBox:/s/src/scripted/image$ fdisk -l test

Disk test: 3072 MB, 3072000000 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 373 cylinders, total 6000000 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x4b8bbe0f

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
 test1   *        2048       67583       32768    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
 test2           67584      133119       32768   83  Linux
 test3          133120     5999999     2933440    5  Extended
 test5          135168     1708031      786432   83  Linux
 test6         1710080     3282943      786432   83  Linux
 test7         3284992     3416063       65536   83  Linux
 test8         3418112     3428351        5120   83  Linux
 test9         3430400     3440639        5120   83  Linux
 test10        3442688     3452927        5120   83  Linux
 test11        3454976     3465215        5120   83  Linux
 test12        3467264     3991551      262144   83  Linux
 test13        3993600     4255743      131072   83  Linux
 test14        4257792     4268031        5120   83  Linux
 test15        4270080     4280319        5120   83  Linux
 test16        4282368     5999999      858816   83  Linux
steve@steve-VirtualBox:/s/src/scripted/image$ sudo losetup /dev/loop0 test -o 34603008
steve@steve-VirtualBox:/s/src/scripted/image$ sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/loop0
mke2fs 1.42 (29-Nov-2011)
Discarding device blocks: done                            
Filesystem label=
OS type: Linux
Block size=4096 (log=2)
Fragment size=4096 (log=2)
Stride=0 blocks, Stripe width=0 blocks
185472 inodes, 741552 blocks
37077 blocks (5.00%) reserved for the super user
First data block=0
Maximum filesystem blocks=763363328
23 block groups
32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group
8064 inodes per group
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912

Allocating group tables: done                            
Writing inode tables: done                            
Creating journal (16384 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done 

steve@steve-VirtualBox:/s/src/scripted/image$ sudo losetup -d /dev/loop0
steve@steve-VirtualBox:/s/src/scripted/image$ fdisk -l test
Warning: invalid flag 0x0000 of partition table 5 will be corrected by w(rite)

Disk test: 3072 MB, 3072000000 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 373 cylinders, total 6000000 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x4b8bbe0f

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
 test1   *        2048       67583       32768    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
 test2           67584      133119       32768   83  Linux
 test3          133120     5999999     2933440    5  Extended
steve@steve-VirtualBox:/s/src/scripted/image$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the blocks count in your `mkfs.ext4` command.

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/loop0 32768
```

Without it, mkfs creates a filesystem with the maximal size and `losetup -o [offset]` creates a devices starting at `[offset]` but ending at the end of the file. Therefore the other partitions get corrupted. It corrupts the partition table because you're using an extended partition, which stores the remaining partition info at the location of that partition.

Another point would be to use a GUID partition table (GPT) which doesn't limit the number of partition thus not needing extended partition. This will not solve your problem but it might be easier to manage those partitions. (Maybe LVM too, but I don't know it.)

Comment: Specifying the block count when performing the format is indeed the solution. Thanks.